# Find most numbers occurrences in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    number_list = list(numbers_str)
    for i in number_list:
        i=max(number_list,key=number_list.count)
    print(i)

def test_print_most_numbers_occurrences():
    print_most_numbers_occurrences('2 3 40 1 5 4 3 3 9  9')
    print_most_numbers_occurrences('9 30 3 9 3 1 4')
    print_most_numbers_occurrences('19 30 13 4 9 3 1 4')


def main():
    print(test_print_most_numbers_occurrences())


main()
```

output

```
None
```

It works when I try this way:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 45, 55, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 545, 56, 6, 7, 67]
>>> max(lst,key=lst.count)
4
```

I want to identify the number that occurred the highest number of times. I'm not sure where i did wrong for first def function.

Comment: Get rid of your loop. And do `numbers_str.split()` instead of `list(numbers_str)`

Comment: Note to all of the answers (that's hinted at by the comment above): the argumentless `.split()` will deal with the double-spaces by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to parse your input correctly. You can't just use `split(" ")` on its own since one of your inputs had a double space.

Secondly, you don't need a loop since `max` does the looping for you.

```
def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    number_list = [int(x) for x in numbers_str.split()]
    i=max(number_list,key=number_list.count)
    print(i)
```

Since you were looping I took the liberty to assume you were trying to deal with the case where multiple numbers might have equal occurrences (e.g: `'2 3 40 1 5 4 3 3 9 9 9'`). In that case, the following code would get all maximums:

```
def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    print(numbers_str.split(" "))
    number_list = [int(x) for x in numbers_str.split()]
    most_occurances = []
    for i in set(number_list):
        occurances = number_list.count(i)
        if len(most_occurances) == 0:
            most_occurances.append(i)
        elif most_occurances[0] < occurances:
            most_occurances = [i]
        elif most_occurances[0] == occurances:
            most_occurances.append(i)
    print(most_occurances)
```

Here's a more concise version that uses slightly more complex code:

```
def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    number_list = [int(x) for x in numbers_str.split()]
    result = {i : number_list.count(i) for i in set(number_list)}
    highest = max(result.values())
    most_occurances = [k for k, v in result.items() if v == highest]
    print(most_occurances)
```

If you need highly efficient code, it is wise to use `collections` `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    number_list = [int(x) for x in numbers_str.split()]
    result = Counter(number_list)
    highest = max(result.values())
    most_occurances = [k for k, v in result.items() if v == highest]
    print(most_occurances if len(most_occurances) > 1 else most_occurances[0])
```

Comment: The output should be 9 and 3 for string('9 30 3 9 3 1 4')

Comment: It is. It's a list: `[9, 3]`. Would you prefer it in some other format? I am referring to the second and third posted methods (the first one only gets a single max).

Comment: How to remove square brackets for the output of third method?

Comment: So you could either turn all the list results into strings: `print(" ".join(map(str, most_occurances)))` (`map` is required to convert the `int` values to strings). Otherwise, you could conditionally print on list length: `print(most_occurances if len(most_occurances) > 1 else most_occurances[0])`. Note, I've changed the third method slightly to work with either of these changes.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I recommend refactoring to use `str.split()` rather than `string.split(" ") if x.isdigit()`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen, good idea. However, for anyone with slightly different input, the second form will handle input like letters gracefully. (Incase that's a possibility).

Answer (score 2):

Use .split(' ') instead of list()

```
string = '9 30 3 9 3 1 4'
lst = map(int, filter(None, string.split(' ')))
print(max(lst, key = lambda x: lst.count(x)))
# returns 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `str.split()` to break your string into a list. Then, you can use `map` to convert the strings into integer. A `collections.Counter` can be used to count the occurrence of each integer in a relatively efficient manner. Finally, `max` with a lambda argument to key over the number of occurrences can be used to pull out the target value.

```
string_list = '2 3 40 1 5 4 3 3 9  9'.split()
int_list = map(int, string_list)

from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(int_list)
target_value, occurrence_count = max(counter.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])
```

Note that no argument is provided to `str.split` and the use of `list.count` is avoided (which is quite inefficient in this scenario). If you want to get all of the target values with the maximum number of occurrences, you can abandon that last line and use:

```
max_occurrences = max(counter.values())
target_values = [k for k, v in counter.items() if v == max_occurrences]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a couple issues with the code as it currently stands.  You seem to be printing the result of a function that returns `None` and you're not splitting your string properly:

```
def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    number_list = [int(number) for number in numbers_str.split(' ') if number != ""]
    for i in number_list:
        i=max(number_list,key=number_list.count)
    print(i, number_list.count(i))

def test_print_most_numbers_occurrences():
    print_most_numbers_occurrences('2 3 40 1 5 4 3 3 9  9')
    print_most_numbers_occurrences('9 30 3 9 3 1 4')
    print_most_numbers_occurrences('19 30 13 4 9 3 1 4')


def main():
    test_print_most_numbers_occurrences()


main()
```

Comment: You're right ,but how to get output 9,3 for string('9 30 3 9 3 1 4') ?

Comment: @Kee Updated the code. It now uses the `.count` function to find the number of occurrences.

Comment: Which version of python are you using

Comment: python3.6 lastest version

Comment: I actually want to get double max for  for string('9 30 3 9 3 1 4')

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write your code as:

```
>>> import re
>>> x
'2     3   40    1  5 4  3  3 9  9'
>>> list = re.sub(' +', ' ', x).split(' ')
>>> list
['2', '3', '40', '1', '5', '4', '3', '3', '9', '9']
>>> max(list, key=list.count)
'3'
>>> x = '19 30 13 4 9 3 1 4'
>>> list = re.sub(' +', ' ', x).split(' ')
>>> list
['19', '30', '13', '4', '9', '3', '1', '4']
>>> max(list, key=list.count)
'4'
>>>
```

so your function should be as:

```
def fun(num_string):
    num_list = re.sub(' +', ' ', num_string).split(' ')
    print(max(num_list, key=num_list.count))  # you can write print but I prefer you should use return max(num_list, key=num_list.count)
```